# Venn diagram applied problem

Tags: probability, statistics

> Among a group 15% speak French, 45% are women, and 20% of the women also speak French.
>
> **Q:** What percentage are women that don't speak French, what percentage only speak French and not woman?

My thoughts:

(1) Using a venn diagram[image]

Let $A = \text{French}$ and $B = \text{Women}$

Since $B = (B \cap A^{c}) \space \cap (B \cap A)$, we have to find $B \cap \overline{B \cap A}$ right?

What is the way? Is the answer $45% - 20% = 25%? But I don't see the manipulation of formulas behind it. Like the way I was trying?

Comment: Note that the statement "20% of the women speak French" is different from "20% are women and speak French". Your Venn diagram implies the second one.

Comment: So now can you re-do your (very pretty) Venn Diagram so it has the correct percentages in each of the regions? Maybe put a box around it to include the whole group; then what percentage are outside both circles? Also consider this: if it were _50%_ (not 15%) French speakers, do you see that doing it your way would give percentages adding to more than 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify our thinking, let's just say we have a 100 people. We're basically told that 15 of these people speak French and that 45 are women. We're also told that 20% of the women speak French. In other words 1/5 of the women speak French. That is, $45*\frac{1}{5}=9$ women speak French.
Let's address the first question: out of the 100 people, how many are non-French speaking women? Well we found that 9 women speak French, so 36 women don't. So out of the 100 people, 36 people are non-French speaking women. So 36%.
As for the second question, we established at the start that 15 people speak French. We also know that there are 9 French-speaking women. So we must have 15-9=6 men that speak French. So that gives us 6%.

Comment: Nice and simple!

Answer (score 1):

$20\%$ **of the women** speak French means that $20\%\cdot45\%=9\%$ **of the group** are women who speak French.

So women who don't speak French are $45\%-9\%=36\%$

Speak French and not women are $15\%-9\%=6\%$

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that your Venn Diagram is a *bit* incorrect.

Since we have 20% of the women speaking French that would be $45\%\cdot 20\%=9\%$ total.

So the amount of women that don't speak French is 36%.

The amount of men that speak French is 6%.